# Python Exception handling in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have exception handling in my app engine app. The code work perfectly fine on the dev server. But when I upload the file on the app engine server, I get a syntax error.

Here is the traceback:

```
Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 68, in get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = resolver.resolve(request.path)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 162, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 118, in resolve
    return self.callback, args, kwargs
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 125, in _get_callback
    self._callback = getattr(__import__(mod_name, {}, {}, ['']), func_name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/foundationofwikipedia/1-1.345018280774164953/src/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    import search_list
  File "/base/data/home/apps/foundationofwikipedia/1-1.345018280774164953/src/search_list.py", line 32
     except Exception as error:
                       ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not understand this as the code works fine in the dev server. It is probably something trivial. HELP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running python 2.6+ on your dev server.  App Engine runs on python 2.5.2, which doesn't have the `except Exception as foo:` syntax.  Replace `as` with a `,`, and while you're at it, install Python 2.5 on your dev machine.